# Can an application depend on two different versions of libstdc++?

Tags: c++, apache, libstdc++

Can an application depend on two different versions of libstdc++ at the same time? (e.g.: libstdc++5 and libstdc++6)?  The scenario being - some binary depends on libstdc++ 6 but loads an .so that depends on libstdc++5...

Will that have any chance of working?

Comment: See [Multiple ABI Testing](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html#abi.testing.multi) in the manual, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1682402/981959

Answer (score 3):

Most importantly, you need to check if those two versions of the library are binary compatible or not. G++ 3.3 and 3.4 are not, for example.

And even if they are:
* There can be name mangling issues
* You cannot do cross module allocation/deallocation (a bad idea anyway)
* You probably can't work around modules with STL

Answer (score 1):

I just recently ported a C++ application from AS3/GCC323 to AS4/GCC346. Although the app itself linked to libstdc++.so.6 some of the libraries it linked to were still linking to libstdc++.so.5. Depsite building successfully it SEGV'ed when i tried to run it.

Once I recompiled the libraries on AS4/GCC346 as well, the app and the libraries only linked to libstdc++.so.6 and the SEGV's no longer occurred.

So i would say the answer is no you can't link to both.

Jon